# Best way to use QueryRenderer in Relay Modern

Tags: graphql, relay, relaymodern

I recently started grokking Relay Modern. I understand that QueryRenderer is used to fetch data using GraphQL query, your root component will have query renderer and all the child components define the data they need in terms of GraphQL fragments.
But is having just one QueryRenderer a good way to go ahead, wouldn't it be difficult pass the query and fragment parameters way upto the root?
If we are having multiple QueryRenderer we are not really making use of Relay caching mechanism as each QueryRenderer creates it's own store tree.

Any thoughts or best practices on how to use QueryRenderer is much appreciated.